# How to fix failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/zakouz/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Tags: laravel

> Warning:
>   require(/home/zakouz/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/zakouz/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/zakouz/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/zakouz/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Comment: did you install composer packages ?

Comment: It seems that your code doesn't find the file - the error message says that. But to get help from SO members, **you should show the code that results in this error message, and also share information about the context**. For SO members your "line 66" doesn't say anything, and the error could be almost anything.

Answer (score 4):

Run `composer dump-autoload` and restart your app. And have you installed all the dependecies? If not then run `php artisan install` first.